# Updating db Model in apply_async not executes

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make non blocking http request with pool.apply_async and after getting response, update existing db raw with new value. Everything is going ok till I'm trying to update the value, i receive error 'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context'. Can you help me yo understand why?

models.py

```
class Proxy(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Proxy'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ip_address = Column(db.String(20))
    port_number = Column(db.String(7))
    proxy_type = Column(db.String(7))
    username = Column(String(100))
    password = Column(String(100))
    status = Column(Integer, default=0)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.id'))
    proxies = relationship("User", backref=backref("Proxies", cascade="all,delete"))

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        db.Model.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}:{}@{}:{}'.format(self.username, self.password, self.ip_address, self.port_number)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

routers.py

```
from app.base.models import Proxy 
pool = Pool(10)
proxy = ProxyModel.query.join(UserModel).filter(UserModel.id == current_user.id).filter(ProxyModel.id == proxy_id).first()

pool.apply_async(long_running_job, args=[proxy])

def long_running_job(proxy):
    proxies = {
        "http": "socks5h://" + str(proxy) if proxy.proxy_type == 'socks5' else "http://" + str(proxy),
        "https": "socks5h://" + str(proxy) if proxy.proxy_type == 'socks5' else "https://" + str(proxy),
    }
    with suppress(Exception):
        response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/', proxies=proxies, timeout=5)

        if response and 'Unsupported get request' in response.text:
            print('Valid')
            proxy.status = 1
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            print('INValid')
            proxy.status = -1
            db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons to fail:

1. `apply_async` expects args to be a tuple. Use `pool.apply_async(long_running_job, args=(proxy,))` instead
2. As the method say, the operation is asynchronous, so it can be finished anytime. You can use the `callback` parameter to see when it has finished by putting, for example: `callback=lambda x: print("Finished task")`
3. Any other error happened. To track this errors you can use the `error_callback` parameter, for example: `error_callback=lambda x: print(x)`, to print the errors
4. The processes don't share memory. Maybe you're trying to access a variable that it's in the other process, like the db. Some db connections cannot be shared between processes.

Hope any of this helps!